# I am trying to convert CVS to EXCEL IN VBSCRIPT

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to convert cvs to excel in vbscript. I want user to input cvs file address and then use that input as file address to convert excel. I know, how to convert to excel without the input . I can put file address manually and it works . It does not work when I use it as input. I am new here and new to visual basic. This is my first code in visual basic.

```
makali.Visible=true
makali.WorkBooks.OpenText "Input", , , xlDelimited, , , , , True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By quoting the first argument in your

```
makali.WorkBooks.OpenText "Input", , , xlDelimited, , , , , True
```

Excel tries to open a file named Input; just loose the quotes to work with the content/value of the variable..